Is there a specific order to get an ability stat beyond 20?
With the Ability Improvement feat (unlockable every 4 levels, starting from any class level 4), you can choose to increase an ability by 2. This is capped at 20.
But there are other ways to permanently increase abilities.
My question is: if I use the other ways before doing the stat increase, can I still increase the stat beyond 20 using the stat increase from the feat? Or do I need to wait to do that after taking the feat (several times)?

Yes, you can take the Ability Score Improvement (ASI) feat before or after a permanent ability increase. This is because the permanent increases apply after your ASI. So if you ASI up to 20, the permanent increases will bump you over 20, whether you obtained them before or after.
As shown here:

Auntie Ethel's Boon increases my Dex by 1, after my starting class bonus (the +2 or +1 you get at level 1). When I am  in the level up screen, it doesn't even get taken into consideration:

When continuing on to level 4, I can select 2 points in Dex and it's still showing only 19 in the leveling screen:

But then as I return to the world, it registers the boon after:

Finally, after reaching level 8 and putting another point into Dex, then returning to the world, we can see that my Dex is now 21:

